# Is there an Apache release for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

Is there an Apache binary that I can install on Mac without having to install MacPorts or MAMP or anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's included by default on all Mac computers.

`/usr/sbin/httpd`

Comment: ...started and stopped as *Web Sharing* in *System Preferences » Sharing*.

Comment: but is there a package I can download from apache? I don't like the pre-installed stuff, I'd like to be able to upgrade and not have to wait for apple, I need more control over it

Comment: @user893730 - No, but you could always build it from source. It's not that hard.